# How to retrieve values from a Map within a List Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, hashmap

I have a list that contains single values and maps from which I want to filter data.
E.g.

```
 List _filters = [];
  String _minPrice = '';
  String _maxPrice = '';
 //_filters = ['Car', 'House', 6, {'minPrice': '5000', 'maxPrice': '6000'}]
```

I want to be able to access the minPrice and the maxPrice so that I can use them but I'm not sure how to access them.

```
  String get minPrice {
    return _minPrice;
  }

   String get maxPrice {
    return _maxPrice;
  }
```

The list is dynamic and at no particular order.
The use case is where a user is filtering data and one of the filters is

```
{'minPrice' : '5000', 'maxPrice': '6000'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list.whereType(), as per this example in order to access by type. https://coflutter.com/dart-filter-items-in-a-list-by-type/

This is complete code to get the property,

```
 List _filters = ['Car', 'House', 6, {'minPrice': '5000', 'maxPrice': '6000'}];
  final iterableMap = _filters.whereType<Map>().first;
  print(iterableMap['minPrice']);
```

If you want to access all the maps then you can use following :

```
// this will return iterable
final iterableMap = _filters.whereType<Map>();
if (!iterableMap.moveNext()) {
    final map = iterableMap.current(); 
}
```

Comment: I've made an edit to my post. This will only work if the list is constant but what if I just want to access that map from whatever position in the list? How do I look for that particular value?

Comment: @TimMwaura,Are you sure it's a list and not JSON?

Comment: Yes it's a List

Comment: @TimMwaura, Edited my code, I have used whereTo method which returns Iteratable and from Iteratable I am fetching the first element, You can also use "for each" on the returned Iteratable, if you want to iter on all the maps in the list. hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I wouldn't have thought of that